# Azure - Automated recommendation management is disabled because Query Store has reached its capacity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We enabled, Automatic tuning in Azure a while ago but when I checked it today, it displays the below message and appears that the Automatic tuning is not funtionaing.

> Automated recommendation management is disabled because Query Store
> has reached its capacity limit and is not collecting new data. Learn
> more about the retention policies to maintain Query Store so new data
> can be collected.

Where can I check/set this Query Store capacity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only when the Query Store is in read-only mode do we get this warning. Double-check your query store's settings.

> Try explicitly setting the read-write mode and rechecking the real
> state to restore Query Store.
>
> If the situation persists, it implies that the Query Store data has
> been corrupted and is persisting on the disc. Within the impacted
> database, run the sp_query_store_consistency_check stored procedure to
> restore Query Store.

**NOTE:** Query Store functionality was added to track performance and is currently in development. There are certain restrictions that are well-known.

> It currently does not function with read-only databases (Including
> read-only AG replicas). Because the query store on reading secondary
> Replicas is read-only, the query store on those secondary replicas is
> read-only as well. This means that the query store does not collect
> runtime statistics for queries conducted on those replicas.

If you checked it and it's set to read-write, we're probably dealing with a problem. The best thing could be raising posting it in Microsoft QnA for more insights and help.

Answer (score 0):

> Typically, you find that Query Store transitioned to read-only mode because the size quota was exceeded.

Reference for this is [Best practices with Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **Verify that Query Store collects query data continuously**
>
> Query Store can silently change the operation mode. Regularly monitor the state of Query Store to ensure that Query Store is operating, and to take action to avoid failures due to preventable causes. Execute the following query to determine the operation mode and view the most relevant parameters:
>
> ```
> USE [QueryStoreDB];
> GO
>
> SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,
>     max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason, interval_length_minutes,
>     stale_query_threshold_days, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc,
>     query_capture_mode_desc
> FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
> ```
>
> The difference between the actual_state_desc and desired_state_desc indicates that a change of the operation mode occurred automatically. The most common change is for Query Store to silently switch to read-only mode. In extremely rare circumstances, Query Store can end up in the ERROR state because of internal errors.
>
> When the actual state is read-only, use the readonly_reason column to determine the root cause. Typically, you find that Query Store transitioned to read-only mode because the size quota was exceeded. In that case, the readonly_reason is set to 65536.
>
> Consider the following steps to switch Query Store to read-write mode and activate data collection:
>
> - Increase the maximum storage size by using the MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB option of ALTER DATABASE.
> - Clean up Query Store data by using the following statement:
>
>   - `ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;`

To change the quota:

> The following script sets a new value for Max Size (MB):
>
> ```
> ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]
> SET QUERY_STORE (MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB = 1024);
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the operation mode to read_write and verify it stays in that state.

```
ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);    
GO  

SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,   
max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason, interval_length_minutes,   
stale_query_threshold_days, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc,   
query_capture_mode_desc  
FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
```

If that does not work, try to clear the Query Store and set it to read-write operation again with below statements:

```
ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;  
GO  

ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB]   
SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);    
GO  

SELECT actual_state_desc, desired_state_desc, current_storage_size_mb,   
    max_storage_size_mb, readonly_reason, interval_length_minutes,   
    stale_query_threshold_days, size_based_cleanup_mode_desc,   
    query_capture_mode_desc  
FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
```